# Selecting droppable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop my widget into my div. I drag my widget over my div, but it doesnt drop the true place.

Here is my example: jsfiddle.net/Mg6V3/15

My goal is when i drop the widget on "1", widget must be drop in it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need #bigContainer to stay droppable after dropping "grid" onto it?

Comment: Yes also i need it. But here my problem is i couldn't drop on #fourGrid_1 or #fourGrid_2 etc. I tried to use "over" event but it is not perfect solution. I have lots of div and grid, so i don't want to write code for each element.

Comment: Hmm, that pose as problem since you can't easily have nested droppable targets.

Comment: Yes, the keyword is this. I will research about nested droppable targets. I will share my solution when i find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I originally thought it would be.

First of all, there is [greedy](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-greedy) option you can set when initializing droppable. It aims to stop drop events from being propagated to all droppable parent when using nested droppables.

Second of all, binding the droppable behavior to matched selectors isn't a constant process. Meaning, that when using something like `$('.test').droppable()` it will bind droppable only to applicable elements that already exists in the DOM. If you create new ones you're suppose to initialize droppable on them on your own.

Here's the working example based on your code. I tried to be minimize the changes - it can be done better, cleaner but it's just an illustration so I guess it's ok. http://jsfiddle.net/vM3dU/